# HTML CSS JS , can't open the live code editor i made

Tags: javascript

I made live code editor, it is html file (with JS CSS HTML no frameworks) inside folder, when i double click it, it works perfectly in my browser.
However when i put link to it in my website (in the link i put the folder/file name), after you click ,browser is empty

i don't know if i am allowed to post link to my website, so i won't for now.
this is the editor:
problem again: works fine when you double click on it, but when i click button (with link to the folder / file name.html) browser is empty.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.9/ace.js"></script>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      #editor {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      #iframe {
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
      }
      #container {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body onload="ready()">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="editor"></div>
      <iframe id="iframe" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
    </div>
    <script>
      function update() {
        var idoc = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document;
        idoc.open();
        idoc.write(editor.getValue());
        idoc.close();
      }
      function setupEditor() {
        window.editor = ace.edit("editor");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
        editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
        editor.setValue(
          `<!-- Example -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Guide</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
`,
          1
        ); //1 = moves cursor to end

        editor.getSession().on("change", function() {
          update();
        });

        editor.focus();

        editor.setOptions({
          fontSize: "16pt",
          showLineNumbers: false,
          showGutter: false,
          vScrollBarAlwaysVisible: true,
          enableBasicAutocompletion: false,
          enableLiveAutocompletion: false
        });

        editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
        editor.setBehavioursEnabled(false);
      }

      function ready() {
        setupEditor();
        update();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, looks like this will not work on local host.
I had to upload this to the host company server, now it works.